# Chrome console object

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

When I write this in the console it's log undefined.

```
var obj = { first: 'lorem' };
```

[image]

But when I write this in the console it's log object.

```
var obj = { first: 'lorem' };
obj = { second: 'ipsum' };
```

[image]

Why is this happening?

Comment: When you execute something in the console, the return value is displayed below your input. For example if you execute `1 + 2`, the console will display `3` since that's the result. Shortly put, the result of a variable declaration is `undefined`, the result of assignment is the assigned value.

Answer (score 1):

The value you see being printed is the `return` value of the line of code you executed.

`var obj = {first: 'lorem'};`

returns `undefined`, whereas

`obj = {second: 'ipsum'};`

will return the object assigned to `obj`, hence `{second: 'ipsum'}` is printed.

This is why you can do things such as:

```
var a = b = 2;
```

Here the assignment of `b = 2` will set `b` equal to 2, whilst *also* returning `2`, thus setting `a` to `2`

Answer (score 0):

Anything you execute in the console, it will display the return value of it. When declaring and assigning variables, it will return undefined. When only assigning values to variables, that value is returned.